# Bluemix - Manual Deploy of NodeJS app Mongo works, DevOps Pipeline fails Using same commands

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops-services

I am trying to automate the creation of my nodeJS application + Compose MongoDB to be able to put on the IBM Marketplace.

Background: I can successfully manually install (via terminal) both the App (NodeJS) and Compose and get this running on Bluemix.

code from my DevOps service deploy stage:

```
#!/bin/bash
cf create-service compose-for-mongodb Standard mongodbbuzzy01
cf push "${CF_APP}" --no-start
mongourl=$(cf env ${CF_APP} | egrep -o 'mongodb://.*"' | rev | cut -c 2- | rev); cf set-env ${CF_APP} MONGO_URL $mongourl
packagejson=$(<bluemix_settings.json)
rooturl=$(awk '$0 ~ /application_uris/{getline n; gsub("\"|^[[:space:]]+","",n); print n}')
cf set-env ${CF_APP} METEOR_SETTINGS "$packagejson"
cf set-env ${CF_APP} ROOT_URL "https://$rooturl" 
cf restage "${CF_APP}"
cf start "${CF_APP}"
```

My Manifest file:

```
declared-services: 
      mongodbbuzzy01: 
        label: compose-for-mongodb
        plan: Standard
applications:
- name:    buzzyAG
  host:    buzzyAG
  services:
    - mongodbbuzzy01
```

When I start the app I see the errors below referring to missing Node modules.

This does NOT happen when I setup this manually (without Dev Ops services), the app starts up fine and all is good. (ie I just run those CF commands via a terminal/shell)

Any help appreciated.

I see the following errors in the logs in the Bluemix console for the app:
```

```
All
Errors
Log type: all
App instances: all
API/1Created app with guid fbd4d954-f2f3-455f-a4a8-8f6d5580d4b8Mar 10, 2017 12:10:36 PM
API/1Updated app with guid fbd4d954-f2f3-455f-a4a8-8f6d5580d4b8 ({"route"=>"28f61a24-cfd1-4dfa-9a9f-4144628db6e0", :verb=>"add", :relation=>:routes, :related_guid=>"28f61a24-cfd1-4dfa-9a9f-4144628db6e0"})Mar 10, 2017 12:10:39 PM
API/6Updated app with guid fbd4d954-f2f3-455f-a4a8-8f6d5580d4b8 ({"environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN"})Mar 10, 2017 12:18:51 PM
API/1Updated app with guid fbd4d954-f2f3-455f-a4a8-8f6d5580d4b8 ({"environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN"})Mar 10, 2017 12:24:26 PM
API/3Updated app with guid fbd4d954-f2f3-455f-a4a8-8f6d5580d4b8 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading swift_buildpack_v2_0_3-20161217-1748...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading sdk-for-nodejs_v3_9-20161128-1327...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading python_buildpack...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading liberty-for-java_v3_6-20161209-1351...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading php_buildpack...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded python_buildpackMar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded sdk-for-nodejs_v3_9-20161128-1327Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading staticfile_buildpack...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading xpages_buildpack...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded swift_buildpack_v2_0_3-20161217-1748Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading binary_buildpack...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded liberty-for-java_v3_6-20161209-1351Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading dotnet-core_v1_0_1-20161005-1225...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading swift_buildpack...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded php_buildpackMar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded xpages_buildpackMar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading liberty-for-java...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded binary_buildpackMar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading sdk-for-nodejs...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading dotnet-core...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded staticfile_buildpackMar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded swift_buildpackMar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading ruby_buildpack...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded sdk-for-nodejsMar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading java_buildpack...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded dotnet-core_v1_0_1-20161005-1225Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading nodejs_buildpack...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded liberty-for-javaMar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloading go_buildpack...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded java_buildpackMar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded dotnet-coreMar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded ruby_buildpackMar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded go_buildpackMar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Creating containerMar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Downloaded nodejs_buildpackMar 10, 2017 12:24:33 PM
STG/0Successfully created containerMar 10, 2017 12:24:36 PM
STG/0Downloading app package...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:36 PM
STG/0Staging...Mar 10, 2017 12:24:37 PM
STG/0Downloaded app package (9.7M)Mar 10, 2017 12:24:37 PM
STG/0 Using default npm version: 2.15.9Mar 10, 2017 12:24:46 PM
STG/0-----&gt; Restoring cacheMar 10, 2017 12:24:46 PM
STG/0 Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)Mar 10, 2017 12:24:47 PM
STG/0-----&gt; Checking and configuring service extensions before installing dependenciesMar 10, 2017 12:24:47 PM
STG/0-----&gt; Building dependenciesMar 10, 2017 12:24:47 PM
STG/0 Installing node modules (package.json)Mar 10, 2017 12:24:47 PM
STG/0 &gt; fibers@1.0.15 install /tmp/app/node_modules/fibersMar 10, 2017 12:24:54 PM
STG/0 > node build.js || nodejs build.jsMar 10, 2017 12:24:54 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:24:54 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:24:54 PM
STG/0 `linux-x64-46` exists; testingMar 10, 2017 12:24:54 PM
STG/0 Binary is fine; exitingMar 10, 2017 12:24:54 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:24:56 PM
STG/0 > node-gyp rebuildMar 10, 2017 12:24:56 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:24:56 PM
STG/0 > bcrypt@0.8.7 install /tmp/app/node_modules/bcryptMar 10, 2017 12:24:56 PM
STG/0 make: Entering directory `/tmp/app/node_modules/bcrypt/build'Mar 10, 2017 12:25:00 PM
STG/0 CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.oMar 10, 2017 12:25:00 PM
STG/0 CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.oMar 10, 2017 12:25:01 PM
STG/0 CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.oMar 10, 2017 12:25:01 PM
STG/0 SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.nodeMar 10, 2017 12:25:03 PM
STG/0 COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.nodeMar 10, 2017 12:25:03 PM
STG/0 make: Leaving directory `/tmp/app/node_modules/bcrypt/build'Mar 10, 2017 12:25:03 PM
STG/0 > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:05 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:05 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:05 PM
STG/0 > websocket@1.0.24 install /tmp/app/node_modules/watson-developer-cloud/node_modules/websocketMar 10, 2017 12:25:05 PM
STG/0 make: Entering directory `/tmp/app/node_modules/watson-developer-cloud/node_modules/websocket/build'Mar 10, 2017 12:25:06 PM
STG/0 CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.oMar 10, 2017 12:25:06 PM
STG/0 SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.nodeMar 10, 2017 12:25:07 PM
STG/0 COPY Release/bufferutil.nodeMar 10, 2017 12:25:08 PM
STG/0 CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.oMar 10, 2017 12:25:08 PM
STG/0 SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.nodeMar 10, 2017 12:25:09 PM
STG/0 COPY Release/validation.nodeMar 10, 2017 12:25:09 PM
STG/0 make: Leaving directory `/tmp/app/node_modules/watson-developer-cloud/node_modules/websocket/build'Mar 10, 2017 12:25:09 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:14 PM
STG/0 > phantomjs@1.9.20 install /tmp/app/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/phantomjsMar 10, 2017 12:25:14 PM
STG/0 > node install.jsMar 10, 2017 12:25:14 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:14 PM
STG/0 PhantomJS not found on PATHMar 10, 2017 12:25:15 PM
STG/0 Saving to /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2Mar 10, 2017 12:25:15 PM
STG/0 Downloading https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/releases/download/v1.9.19/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2Mar 10, 2017 12:25:15 PM
STG/0 Receiving...Mar 10, 2017 12:25:15 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:29 PM
STG/0 Received 12854K total.Mar 10, 2017 12:25:29 PM
STG/0 Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:29 PM
STG/0 Copying extracted folder /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1489109129909/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64 -> /tmp/app/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantomMar 10, 2017 12:25:32 PM
STG/0 Removing /tmp/app/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantomMar 10, 2017 12:25:32 PM
STG/0 Done. Phantomjs binary available at /tmp/app/node_modules/webshot/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjsMar 10, 2017 12:25:33 PM
STG/0 Writing location.js fileMar 10, 2017 12:25:33 PM
STG/0 eventie@1.0.6 node_modules/eventieMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 html-truncate@1.2.2 node_modules/html-truncateMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 underscore@1.8.3 node_modules/underscoreMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 jquery-inview@1.1.2 node_modules/jquery-inviewMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 vimeo-api@1.1.0 node_modules/vimeo-apiMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 └── cookies@0.3.8Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 currency-symbol-map@3.1.0 node_modules/currency-symbol-mapMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── keygrip@1.0.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 autolinker@1.4.2 node_modules/autolinkerMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 get-style-property@0.1.1 node_modules/get-style-propertyMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 in-viewport@3.4.2 node_modules/in-viewportMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 wolfy87-eventemitter@4.3.0 node_modules/wolfy87-eventemitterMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 giphy-api@1.2.5 node_modules/giphy-apiMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 connect-cookies@0.0.0 node_modules/connect-cookiesMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── on-finished@2.3.0 (ee-first@1.1.1)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 fibers@1.0.15 node_modules/fibersMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── bytes@2.4.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 body-parser@1.17.1 node_modules/body-parserMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 └── source-map@0.5.6Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── content-type@1.0.2Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 source-map-support@0.4.11 node_modules/source-map-supportMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── depd@1.1.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── qs@6.4.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 └── type-is@1.6.14 (media-typer@0.3.0, mime-types@2.1.14)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── iconv-lite@0.4.15Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── raw-body@2.2.0 (unpipe@1.0.0)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── http-errors@1.6.1 (setprototypeof@1.0.3, inherits@2.0.3, statuses@1.3.1)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── debug@2.6.1 (ms@0.7.2)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 bcrypt@0.8.7 node_modules/bcryptMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 jquery@2.2.4 node_modules/jqueryMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── bindings@1.2.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 s3-write-stream@0.0.1 node_modules/s3-write-streamMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 └── nan@2.3.5Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── through2@0.4.2 (readable-stream@1.0.34, xtend@2.1.2)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── backoff@2.3.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── stream-browserify@2.0.1 (inherits@2.0.3, readable-stream@2.2.3)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 └── bl@0.7.0 (readable-stream@1.0.34)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 meteor-node-stubs@0.2.5 node_modules/meteor-node-stubsMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── https-browserify@0.0.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── minimalistic-assert@1.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── buffer-shims@1.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── path-browserify@0.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── tty-browserify@0.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── evp_bytestokey@1.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── constants-browserify@1.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── punycode@1.4.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── indexof@0.0.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── browserify-cipher@1.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── string_decoder@0.10.31Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── browserify-des@1.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── create-ecdh@4.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── browserify-rsa@4.0.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── brorand@1.0.6Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── ripemd160@1.0.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── inherits@2.0.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── os-browserify@0.2.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── util-deprecate@1.0.2Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── create-hmac@1.1.4Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── cipher-base@1.0.3Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.7Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── randombytes@2.0.3Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── ieee754@1.1.8Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── core-util-is@1.0.2Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── pbkdf2@3.0.9Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── process@0.11.9Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── stream-browserify@2.0.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── domain-browser@1.1.7Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── miller-rabin@4.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── assert@1.4.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── isarray@1.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── base64-js@1.2.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── create-hash@1.1.2Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── diffie-hellman@5.0.2Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── Base64@0.2.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── vm-browserify@0.0.4Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── buffer-xor@1.0.3Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── date-now@0.1.4Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── hash.js@1.0.3Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── querystring@0.2.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── browserify-sign@4.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── timers-browserify@1.4.2Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── querystring-es3@0.2.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── console-browserify@1.1.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── bn.js@4.11.6Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── des.js@1.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── util@0.10.3Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── elliptic@6.3.2Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── asn1.js@4.9.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── readable-stream@2.2.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── sha.js@2.4.8Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── pako@0.2.9Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── crypto-browserify@3.11.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── browserify-aes@1.0.6Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── http-browserify@1.7.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── url@0.11.0 (punycode@1.3.2)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── browserify-zlib@0.1.4Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── events@1.1.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── public-encrypt@4.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 stripe@4.15.1 node_modules/stripeMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── parse-asn1@5.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 └── buffer@4.9.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 aws-sdk@2.0.0-rc9 node_modules/aws-sdkMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── lodash.isplainobject@4.0.6Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── object-assign@4.1.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 d3@3.5.17 node_modules/d3Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 └── bluebird@2.11.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── qs@6.0.4Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ics-js@0.9.1 node_modules/ics-jsMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── simple-guid@0.0.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 saml2-js@1.11.0 node_modules/saml2-jsMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 └── xml2js@0.2.4 (sax@1.2.2)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── xmldom@0.1.27Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 └── lodash@4.17.4Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── es6-error@1.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── xmlbuilder@0.4.2Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── async@1.5.2Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── underscore@1.6.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── xml-crypto@0.8.5 (xpath.js@1.0.7, xmldom@0.1.19)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── xmlbuilder@2.1.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── vcap_services@0.2.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── xml-encryption@0.9.0 (async@0.2.10, xpath@0.0.5, ejs@0.8.8, node-forge@0.6.38)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 watson-developer-cloud@2.25.1 node_modules/watson-developer-cloudMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── cookie@0.3.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── isstream@0.1.2Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── csv-stringify@1.0.4 (lodash.get@4.4.2)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 └── xml2js@0.4.17 (sax@1.2.2, xmlbuilder@4.2.1)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── debug@1.0.4 (ms@0.6.2)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── object.pick@1.2.0 (isobject@2.1.0)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── extend@3.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── request@2.79.0 (tunnel-agent@0.4.3, aws-sign2@0.6.0, forever-agent@0.6.1, oauth-sign@0.8.2, caseless@0.11.0, is-typedarray@1.0.0, stringstream@0.0.5, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, aws4@1.6.0, uuid@3.0.1, qs@6.3.2, combined-stream@1.0.5, mime-types@2.1.14, tough-cookie@2.3.2, form-data@2.1.2, hawk@3.1.3, http-signature@1.1.1, har-validator@2.0.6)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── solr-client@0.6.0 (duplexer@0.1.1, httperror@0.2.3, JSONStream@1.0.7, request@2.63.0, json-bigint@0.1.4)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── string@3.3.3Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── object.omit@2.0.1 (is-extendable@0.1.1, for-own@0.1.5)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── websocket@1.0.24 (yaeti@0.0.6, typedarray-to-buffer@3.1.2, debug@2.6.1, nan@2.5.1)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 babel-runtime@6.23.0 node_modules/babel-runtimeMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── tmp@0.0.31 (os-tmpdir@1.0.2)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 └── async@2.1.5 (lodash@4.17.4)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 └── phantomjs@1.9.20 (progress@1.1.8, kew@0.7.0, which@1.2.12, request-progress@2.0.1, hasha@2.2.0, extract-zip@1.5.0, fs-extra@0.26.7, request@2.67.0)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── buffer-from@0.1.1 (is-array-buffer-x@1.0.13)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 ├── regenerator-runtime@0.10.3Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 └── core-js@2.4.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0 webshot@0.15.3 node_modules/webshotMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0-----> Checking and configuring service extensions after installing dependenciesMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0-----> Installing App ManagementMar 10, 2017 12:25:34 PM
STG/0-----> Caching buildMar 10, 2017 12:25:38 PM
STG/0 Clearing previous node cacheMar 10, 2017 12:25:38 PM
STG/0 - node_modulesMar 10, 2017 12:25:38 PM
STG/0 Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):Mar 10, 2017 12:25:38 PM
STG/0 - bower_components (nothing to cache)Mar 10, 2017 12:25:43 PM
STG/0-----> Build succeeded!Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── aws-sdk@2.0.0-rc9Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── autolinker@1.4.2Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── babel-runtime@6.23.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── connect-cookies@0.0.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── body-parser@1.17.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── bcrypt@0.8.7Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── currency-symbol-map@3.1.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── fibers@1.0.15Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── giphy-api@1.2.5Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── d3@3.5.17Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── eventie@1.0.6Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── get-style-property@0.1.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── in-viewport@3.4.2Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── ics-js@0.9.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── html-truncate@1.2.2Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── jquery@2.2.4Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── jquery-inview@1.1.2Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── saml2-js@1.11.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── s3-write-stream@0.0.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── source-map-support@0.4.11Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── underscore@1.8.3Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── webshot@0.15.3Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── vimeo-api@1.1.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── meteor-node-stubs@0.2.5Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── stripe@4.15.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 └── wolfy87-eventemitter@4.3.0Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0 ├── watson-developer-cloud@2.25.1Mar 10, 2017 12:25:44 PM
STG/0Exit status 0Mar 10, 2017 12:26:11 PM
STG/0Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...Mar 10, 2017 12:26:11 PM
STG/0Uploading build artifacts cache...Mar 10, 2017 12:26:11 PM
STG/0Staging completeMar 10, 2017 12:26:11 PM
STG/0Uploading droplet...Mar 10, 2017 12:26:11 PM
STG/0Uploaded build artifacts cache (28.2M)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:12 PM
STG/0Uploaded droplet (52.9M)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:18 PM
STG/0Uploading completeMar 10, 2017 12:26:18 PM
STG/0Destroying containerMar 10, 2017 12:26:18 PM
CELL/0Creating containerMar 10, 2017 12:26:18 PM
STG/0Successfully destroyed containerMar 10, 2017 12:26:21 PM
CELL/0Successfully created containerMar 10, 2017 12:26:21 PM
CELL/0Starting health monitoring of containerMar 10, 2017 12:26:26 PM
APP/0> buzzy7@1.0.0 start /home/vcap/appMar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0> node main.jsMar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0module.js:327Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0Error: Cannot find module 'semver'Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0 throw err;Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0 at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0 at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0 at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0 at Module.require (module.js:353:17)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0 at require (internal/module.js:12:17)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0 at Module.require (module.js:353:17)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0 at Module.load (module.js:343:32)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0 ^Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0 at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/programs/server/boot.js:16:5)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! node v4.5.0Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! npm v2.15.9Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! buzzy7@1.0.0 start: `node main.js`Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLEMar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! Exit status 1Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! not with npm itself.Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the buzzy7 package,Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! Failed at the buzzy7@1.0.0 start script 'node main.js'.Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! node main.jsMar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! npm owner ls buzzy7Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! npm bugs buzzy7Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-45-genericMar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:Mar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0npm ERR! /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.logMar 10, 2017 12:26:27 PM
APP/0Exit status 1Mar 10, 2017 12:26:28 PM
CELL/0Exit status 0Mar 10, 2017 12:26:28 PM
CELL/0Destroying containerMar 10, 2017 12:26:28 PM
API/3App instance exited with guid fbd4d954-f2f3-455f-a4a8-8f6d5580d4b8 payload: {&quot;instance&quot;=&gt;&quot;&quot;, &quot;index&quot;=&gt;0, &quot;reason&quot;=&gt;&quot;CRASHED&quot;, &quot;exit_description&quot;=&gt;&quot;2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* 2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Exited with status 1\n* cancelled\n* cancelled&quot;, &quot;crash_count&quot;=&gt;1, &quot;crash_timestamp&quot;=&gt;1489109188042666420, &quot;version&quot;=&gt;&quot;d9951ba7-2814-497d-8872-7b4ab71da4e6&quot;}Mar 10, 2017 12:26:28 PM
CELL/0Creating containerMar 10, 2017 12:26:28 PM
CELL/0Successfully destroyed containerMar 10, 2017 12:26:30 PM
CELL/0Successfully created containerMar 10, 2017 12:26:31 PM
CELL/0Starting health monitoring of containerMar 10, 2017 12:26:35 PM
APP/0> node main.jsMar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0> buzzy7@1.0.0 start /home/vcap/appMar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0 at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0Error: Cannot find module 'semver'Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0 throw err;Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0 at require (internal/module.js:12:17)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0 at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0 at Module.require (module.js:353:17)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0 at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/programs/server/boot.js:16:5)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0module.js:327Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0 ^Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0 at Module.require (module.js:353:17)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0 at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0 at Module.load (module.js:343:32)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-45-genericMar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! node v4.5.0Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! Exit status 1Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! node main.jsMar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! npm v2.15.9Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLEMar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! Failed at the buzzy7@1.0.0 start script 'node main.js'.Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the buzzy7 package,Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! buzzy7@1.0.0 start: `node main.js`Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! npm bugs buzzy7Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! npm owner ls buzzy7Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! not with npm itself.Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:Mar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0npm ERR! /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.logMar 10, 2017 12:26:36 PM
APP/0Exit status 1Mar 10, 2017 12:26:37 PM
CELL/0Exit status 0Mar 10, 2017 12:26:37 PM
CELL/0Destroying containerMar 10, 2017 12:26:37 PM
CELL/0Creating containerMar 10, 2017 12:26:37 PM
CELL/0Successfully destroyed containerMar 10, 2017 12:26:39 PM
CELL/0Successfully created containerMar 10, 2017 12:26:40 PM
CELL/0Starting health monitoring of containerMar 10, 2017 12:26:44 PM
APP/0> node main.jsMar 10, 2017 12:26:45 PM
APP/0> buzzy7@1.0.0 start /home/vcap/appMar 10, 2017 12:26:45 PM
APP/0 throw err;Mar 10, 2017 12:26:45 PM
APP/0 ^Mar 10, 2017 12:26:45 PM
APP/0 at require (internal/module.js:12:17)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:45 PM
APP/0 at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:45 PM
APP/0 at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/programs/server/boot.js:16:5)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:45 PM
APP/0 at Module.load (module.js:343:32)Mar 10, 2017 12:26:45 PM
APP/0Error: Cannot find module 'semver'Mar 10, 2017 12:26:45 PM
```

```

Comment: Hey againsburg, I appreciate the detailed post and logs. Can you post your package.json? It appears there is an issue with the "semver" module.

Comment: @HobertBushIII thanks... yep ran into space issues .. pasting here https://gist.github.com/adamgins/e521e5d654bcd83354313332776da85e  FYI I started getting node errors on a  number of modules.. I tried adding them to the package.json and then just got git with new ones... a lot of these modules are not top level modules I've used but dependent ones. ... so not sure if the node build processes is messing up somehow?

Comment: @ralphearle wondering if any more thoughts on this ,pls

Comment: @aginsburg, I'm contacting the internal DevOps services team again - they have been occupied with their annual IBM developer conference this week and last.

Comment: @aginsburg I missed the update notification and I'm currently reviewing.

Comment: Thanks @HobertBushIII

Comment: Thanks @ralphearle

Comment: @DSX wondering if you got this to work with DevOps Services

Answer (score 1):

The log says that the module `semver` isn't found and it looks like it was never added  to your package.json.

Comment: That's correct but there will be many dependent packages note in package.json as it only includes the root packages I've installed.  Surely it should be able to work this out? Again these errors do NOT occur if it install from the command line with a 'cf push'

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing/renaming your node_modules folder locally and performing an `npm install` and deployment again?  I'm guessing you have something slightly different in your local setup that's allowing it to work.